# To remove a div after a jQuery function complete

Tags: jquery, magento

I have worked on a magento extension. There is an ajax login part in that extension. When I click on the login menu its add a 'div' which have a class name 'tinymask'. Now I want to remove that div or move that div to another div when it is already run.

The div i want to remove:

```html
<div class="tinymask" id="" style="height: 616px; 
     width: 1286px; opacity: 0.2; display: block;"></div>
```

This above div is attached to the body when I click on the login menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery function as you have mention in your question tag line

```
$("body").children(".tinymask").remove();
```

You use [children()(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/children/) because you only want to target direct children of body.

Please set your function at proper place to remove extra div.

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: Actually it used a tinybox jQuery plugin for that login.So i want to run the "$("body").children(".tinymask").remove();" after the tinybox.js execute

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after function or in last line of function

$("body").children(".tinymask").remove();